# Spring @Autowired chains and regular 'new XYZ()' instantiations

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

Is my impression correct that by using the regular `new XYZ()` way of instantiating some component XYZ prevents Spring from processing the `@Autowired` fields inside XYZ?

Second question: is it correct that I cannot use dependency injection in XYZ and at the same time use final fields in XYZ because of that? Example:

```
@Component
public class XYZ {
    @Autowired
    private SomeDep dep;

    private final int value;

    public XYZ(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

How would I make that working?

So, well, accepting there is no nicer way, let's do it that way:

```
@Component
public class XYZ {
    @Autowired
    private SomeDep dep;

    private final int value;

    // factory instantiation
    XYZ() {
        value=0;
    }

    private XYZ(SomeDep dep, int value) {
        this.dep = dep;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public XYZ getInstance(int value) {
        return new XYZ(dep, value);
    }
}
```

??? That is ugly. And it gets even uglier when I want to move the dependency declaration to a parent class....... ??? I always thought DI is nice. I think I have to reconsider that. What are the alternatives? Am I missing something?

Comment: Use factory methods and factory classes

Comment: Which core java language features. If you want a field to be final and you have a dependency for it, use constructor based injection instead of field injection.

Comment: @ Shoaib Chikate: so I am basically forced to use something that I might call a chained-factories-pattern where prototype classes (single instances) get instantiated via @Autowired chains and the actual working copies are created by "getInstance(...)" methods? If yes, well, that's quite ugly.

Comment: final variable thing you can handled using constructor injection as what @M.Deinum said.You can restrict getInstance() to give Singleton object instead of prototype

Comment: can you mix injected final fields with non-injected final fields? How would my example look like if using constructor injection?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you create object with `new`, @Autowired won't work, because this object is created outside of the [Spring IoC container](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html). So this object should be instantiated by spring in order to let it inject dependencies. To get this object (bean) from container (spring application context), you should  [initialize Spring context](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/intro-to-ioc-creating-a-spring-application.html) and call `context.getBean("beanName")`.
2. You can use constructor dependency injection here. [Here](http://spring.io/blog/2007/07/11/setter-injection-versus-constructor-injection-and-the-use-of-required/) you can read more about injection types

Comment: ok, so you are bascially telling me that I should forget about non-injected final fields in spring components?

Comment: No he is saying use constructor injection to set the values for your final fields in the constructor, where you are allowed to set them.